# El for no se repite. solo se ejecuta una vez y no se porque pasa

Tags: c

Solo puedo usar funciones, for, if ,do, while. Y es obligatorio que use funciones

Su equipo de trabajo a sido contratado para realizar la planilla de una empresa que cuenta con Gerentes, supervisores y administrativos, cada uno con una rata por hora diferente que deberá leer. Una vez que conozca la cantidad de empleados de la empresa y cada rata por hora, por cada empleado deberá leer: nombre completo, puesto, horas quincenales trabajadas que, de ser mayor a 40 se pagan a razón de 1.5 por horas extras. Imprima los datos del empleado y su salario final antes de procesar un nuevo empleado. Al final, imprima la planilla total de la empresa.
NOTA: deberá utilizar una función que calcule las horas extras y otra que calcule el salario del empleado

```
 #include <stdio.h>


//Funcion horas extras
// a = a rata, b = hora

float funext(float a, int b){
float res;
res= a*((b-40)*1.5);
return res;
}

//Funcion para el salario normal de las horas extras
float saltot(float a){
float res;
res=a*40;
return res;
}


//Funcion salario del empleado
// a = a rata, b = hora

float funSal(float a,int b){
float res;

res= a*b;

return res;     
 }
//Cuerpo principal
int main()
{
    
    int n, i, hora;
    float rata,total,fun,sal; 
    char puesto;
    char nombre[15];
    
    
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        
        printf("Ingrese los datos del empleado %d\n",(i+1));
        printf("Dependiendo de que posicion trabaja ingrese:\nA Gerente.\nB Supervisor.\nC administrativo.\n");
        scanf("%s",&puesto);
        printf("Nombre\n");
        scanf("%s",&nombre);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Horas trabajadas\n");
        scanf("%d",&hora);
        printf("\n");
        
        
        switch(puesto){
           
            case'A':
             printf("ingrese su saliro minimo\n");
            scanf("%f",&rata);
            
            if(hora>40){
                fun=funext(rata,hora);
                sal=saltot(rata);
                
                printf("Su salario total es de:\n");
                printf("%.2f",sal);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Por las horas extras trabajadas se le pagara:\n");
                printf("%.2f",fun);
            
            }else{
                fun=funSal(rata,hora);
                printf("Su salario total es de:\n");
                printf("%.2f",fun);
            }
            break;
            case'B':
             printf("ingrese su saliro minimo\n");
            scanf("%f",&rata);
            
             if(hora>40){
                 fun=funext(rata,hora);
                 sal=saltot(rata);
                
                printf("Su salario total es de:\n");
                printf("%.2f",sal);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Por las horas extras trabajadas se le pagara:\n");
                printf("%.2f",fun);
                
            }else{
                 fun=funSal(rata,hora);
                 printf("Su salario total es de:\n");
                 printf("%.2f",fun);
            }
            break;
            case'C':
             printf("ingrese su saliro minimo\n");
            scanf("%f",&rata);
            
             if(hora>40){
                 fun=funext(rata,hora);
                 sal=saltot(rata);
                 
                printf("Su salario total es de:\n");
                printf("%.2f",sal);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Por las horas extras trabajadas se le pagara:\n");
                printf("%.2f",fun);
            }else{
                 fun=funSal(rata,hora);
                 printf("Su salario total es de:\n");
                 printf("%.2f",fun);
            }
            break;
            default:
            printf("ERROR opcion incorrecta");
        }
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo que te aconsejo es que coloques los cases del switch entre llaves.

Comment: Parece que pasas la direccion de memoria de un char(`scanf("%s",&nombre[30]);`) en vez de la direccion de memoria se una cadena cadena(`scanf("%s",&nombre[0]);` o `scanf("%s",nombre);`), entonces cuando scanf llega a la posicion 30 del cual no esta disponible, porque tu arreglo tiene un rango de 0-29, el sistema operativo le niega el permiso de escritura de una memoria que no te pertenece causando que scanf falle( No sin antes el sistema operativo cierre tu app) o eso creo.

Comment: acabo de cambiar el [30] a por un [10] pero ahora me sale stack smashing detected y se cierra el programa

Comment: Cambia `scanf("%s",&nombre[30]);` por `scanf("%s",nombre);`. Y asegurate de que el nombre no sea mas grande que `29` caracteres.

Comment: cambie al scanf("%s",nombre); pero sigue sin ejecutarse mas de una vez. y uso nombres de cortos como pedro o juan

Comment: No tienes controles de longitud de la cadena de entrada y, en el caso del `puesto` almacenas una cadena de caracteres en la posición de memoria de un único carácter. Deberías usar la función [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) para limitar el número de caracteres que cargas en memoria

Comment: O usa `scanf(" %c",&puesto);` recuerda inserte el espacio antes y despues del `%c ` para que elimine todos los saltos de lineas y caracter de espacio para que lea el caracter que el usuario ingresó(Nota: Solo es necesesario cuando tratas de leer un solo caracter), y tambien al hacer esto(`scanf("%s",nombre);` ya le pasas la direccion de memoria de la matris(Esto solo se aprica cuando usas una matris o un puntero, cuando no usas un array o un puntero debes usar `&` como ya sabes).